# How can I limit access control for my apps running on cloudbees? (Limit which IP addresses can access the services via browser or api)

Tags: cloudbees

I have deployed my application on cloudbees, and was wondering how I can create a whitelist of allowed IPs which can access the application via browser requests or API requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on RUN@Cloud shared server pool.
Such IP restriction can be configured on "dedicated" servers as they provide more configuration option with isolated setup

Answer (score 0):

You could write a filter (eg a servlet filter) which looks at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For header - this is the IP of the client - and filter it that way if you like.

(you have to use that header as the routing layer will provide it).